# How do I see all the sites I have access to in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

When I land on the Suggested / Featured sites page in Office 365, how can I see ALL the sites that I have permission to access? All I see are suggested and frequent but that's not a full list of my sites?

Answer (score 13):

In the search box on top left corner in office 365 SharePoint home page, type "**contentclass:STS_Site**" and search. It will give you list of all site collections you have access to. If you need to see all site collection + subsites , search for " **contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web**"