# O365 Sharepoint - Show all sites users have access to

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-site

By default sharepoint online has a vertical list on the left of "frequent" sites. Rather than this, I would much prefer the entire tenant just have an alphabetical listing of all sites a user has access to that doesn't change and move around. This feels like something that should be simple but the answer seems to evade me - is it possible?

I see from [another question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207042/how-do-i-see-all-the-sites-i-have-access-to-in-office-365#:%7E:text=In%20the%20search%20box%20on%20top%20left%20corner,subsites%2C%20search%20for%20%22%20contentclass%3ASTS_Site%20OR%20contentclass%3ASTS_Web%20%22) that allows me to search for the same list so this seems halfway there... I also found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166382/displaying-all-sites-a-user-has-access-to-across-an-entire-web-application) which provided a lot of HTML to do this from a webpart but that seemed a bit overkill... is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Search is the only way. You can use an API call or set up a search results page. The details will be up to you.

You'll have to be mindful of paging. Suppose a user has access to thousands of sites. What will you do then? If you try to fetch them all you'll crash the page.